# My code is showing ARRAY

Tags: arrays, wordpress

I am using a plugin, using the following code could show user ratings:

```
<?php $users_rating = RWP_API::get_reviews_box_users_rating( $post_id, $reviews_box_id ); ?>
<?php echo $users_rating; ?>
```

But instead of showing the actual values, I am getting ARRAY writen on my web page.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you,

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based strictly on your example the results of your get_reviews_box_users_rating() method is returning an array. You need to loop through the array itself and echo those values.

```
foreach($users_rating as $k => $rating){
    //IF YOUR ARRAY CONTAINS OBJECTS
    echo $rating->userRating;

    //IF AN ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY
    echo $rating['userRating'];
}
```

To see the structure of the array being returned you can use this:

```
print_r($users_rating);
```

That will let you know if your array is a stdObject Array or an associative array of elements.

Comment: Thank you for your reply bro, here's the array that I have to use:
foreach($reviews as $each_review){
  var_dump($each_review);
  echo $each_review['review_overall_score'];
  echo $each_review['review_user_rating_options'][0];
  echo $each_review['review_users_score']['scores'][0];
  echo $each_review['review_users_score']['scores'][1];
  echo $each_review['review_users_score']['scores'][2];
  echo $each_review['review_users_score']['scores'][3];
  echo $each_review['review_users_score']['count'];
                }

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the documentation to know how to use the API correctly.

Your call to `RWP_API::get_reviews_box_users_rating` tells me you're using the "Reviewer WordPress Plugin" from CodeCanyon.

The first step is looking up that method in the documentation: http://evographics.net/WEB_SERVER/reviewer-plugin-v-3-14-2.pdf

The documentation tells you to expect an array to be returned therefore it's up to you to display those values in a usable format.

```
$users_rating = RWP_API::get_reviews_box_users_rating( $post_id, $reviews_box_id );

// We're going to skip verifying we got back what was expected for the sake of the answer.

// Loop through each user score and display.
foreach ( $users_rating['score'] as $key => $score ) {

    // Example of how an individual score could be displayed.
    printf( 'Score %d: %d<br />', $key, $score );
}
```

Comment: Yeah exactly I'm using the same plugin, got with a website with extended license, so no direct support for me.

Could you please help me to provide a piece of code that can show the overall rating of post on any other part of the same post?

Highly appreciated

Comment: Rough approach, calculate the sum of the values in the score array and divide it by the count. Highly likely the API will have a function to return that value instead but you need to read the documentation